# should i parse Socket.IO messages on server on client

Tags: javascript, node.js

We have a chat implemented with nodejs+socket.io and now we want to add a profanity check that will basically iterate over an array of bad works and check if they exists in the message.

Based on the profanity check we want to put a html element over the message saying "this message contains profanity, do you want to read it?". The answer will be remembered. Also will have a checkbox saying "always show messages containing profanity"

We have a pretty large number of users (I don't have the approximate count of messages / minute) that are chatting constantly (about 3-400 online at any hour) and we expect that number to rapidly increase over this year (3-4x). So should we implement the profanity check on the server or on the client ?

Comment: How *many* "bad" words are we talking about?

Comment: I personally would do that on the client. This way you'd have 400 machines working instead of 1 server. And there's no security of private data issue.

Comment: @NicholasKyriakides about 300 i guess.. multiple languages and multiple variations of the same word

Comment: @JeremyThille i'm thinking about mobile devices also.. on pc/laptops i don't think it would be a problem.. but on mobile browsers and/or (later) mobile app wouldn't it be a problem ?

Comment: No; Searching through <1000 words on any modern device is bound to take <3ms at most. I would do this on the server though solely because the user won't be able to circumvent this by viewing the "bad" words list and for minimising the load time of your app.

Comment: @NicholasKyriakides thank you

Answer (score 0):

It would be a better idea to do it on the server side. If scaling is something you have on your mind then you can always use the [cluster](https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html) module to take advantages of the multi-cores. The latency should be minimal in this case, supporting concurrency to the tune of ~850 users/second